# the_post_thumbnail fetches wrong image

Tags: theme-development, images

We currently have a strange issue with a wordpress site.

We have Featured Images on a good number of pages, including the one that we selected as the start page of the blog – the site uses a custom start page. Alas, instead of pulling the Featured Image for that blog, it takes the image it finds on the first article of the blog.

Which is kind of strange, considering the call is at a place where we haven't entered the loop yet.

So I'm at loss. How can I get the function to output the right image?

(WordPress 3.5.2; Theme “Responsive”)

Comment: What is the code that pulls the image? Have you looked to see if there are [any filters](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php#L85) manipulating things?

Comment: The code that pulls the image is a simple function connected to an action `responsive_wrapper`.

Comment: Please post that code. I have no idea what "simple function" look like and `responsive_wrapper` is not a core hook, it is theme specific, so I have no idea what it does. Post a link to the theme source also.

Answer (score 0):

It's sometimes a pain to work with post page and/or front page. I do not know if it's the best solution for you but to me you'd better use `front-page.php` as the template file for start page.

According to the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Visual_Overview) this is recommanded :

> Used for both Your latest posts or A static page as set in the Front
>   page displays